# Ubuntu 19.10 remove gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, 19.10, ubuntu-gnome

I switched to KDE Plasma, I installed it via apt install kde-full.

I'd like to remove Ubuntu's default DE which is gnome.

What is the safest way? Should I apt remove ubuntu-desktop or apt remove gnome*

I want to keep all desktop capabilities so I can use KDE without any problems.

Comment: I would advise against trying to remove anything. Just choose the kde option at login time.

Comment: In my experience you usually only have problems with 3 or more desktops installed. Yes you'll have larger upgrades (more packages are installed), more complex menus (more applications are installed), can be wasteful with ram (using GTK apps if using Qt (KDE) desktop, or vice-versa, but only an issue if you've limited ram), etc.. but I agree with DK Bose.  *FYI; My Ubuntu install has 3 other DEs installed; though I'd not recommend adding 3 like I did*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those who wants to follow my path here it is. I couldn't do apt remove ubuntu-desktop since it kept saying it isn't installed so I did apt remove gnome* then apt autoremove. It removed everything related to gnome, Ubuntu is restarting/working fine.
Before removing gnome my ram was at 1.2gb idle, now it's at 0.99gb (viewd in system monitor inside kde).

I just hope when upgrading ubuntu to 20 LTS it doesn't throw gnome at me again.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**: dont follow my advice so, its right that it would be very risky delete those things without knowing what it are.
You could only select another desktop from the list, and dont mind about the gnome.

Comment: In order to make the option disappear it is sufficient to delete (or rename) the corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions` or `/usr/share/wayland-sessions`. You shouldn't blindly remove (or suggest to remove) all packages containing "gnome" in their name.